# Static validators emitting "nbsp;"

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a .NET question.  For my particular application which is catoring to mobile devices (specifically blackberry at the moment), I am using validators (required field validator to be exact).

The problem is that I have disabled javascript from asp.net (by specifying ClientTarget="ie4", but setting EnableClientScript="False" on the validator tags has the same effect).  The actual issue is that when the validator is invisible, it emits "nbsp;" instead of nothing, is there some way to override this unwanted result?

Please do not reply solutions that include css or javascript, as I am unable to use either in my particular situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Display=Static means that a single nonbreaking space ("&nbsp") is emitted. This last behavior exists so that table cells containing only validators do not collapse to nothing when valid.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx).

As [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169570/static-validators-emitting-nbsp/5170071#5170071) said, you could try `Display=Dynamic` instead, but if you're insistent on using `Display=Static`, I think your only option is to extend the validator and override the `Render` method.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
   if (this.Display == ValidatorDisplay.Static && this.IsValid)
   {
       writer.Write(String.Empty);
   }
   else
   {
       base.Render(writer);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static validators will indeed render an `&nbsp;` entity when hidden.

Try using dynamic validators instead, by setting their [Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display.aspx) property to `ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic`.